# props.actions `undefined` when using redux and react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I'm following a tutorial from this link: http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/react-redux-tutorial-part-ii-react-router-and-container-components/
But when the `handleSubmit()` function is fired i get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'logInUser' of undefined

Indeed when i try to log `this.props.actions` it's undefined but i don't understand why. Is there something missing?
I'm using Antd as UI framework.

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';  
import {connect} from 'react-redux';  
import * as sessionActions from './actions/sessionActions';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {credentials: {username: '', password: ''}};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const credentials = this.state.credentials;
    credentials[field] = event.target.value;;
    return this.setState({credentials: credentials});
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        //console.log(this.props.actions);
        this.props.actions.logInUser(this.state.credentials);
      }
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'username missing!' }],
          })(
          <Input 
              name="username"
              value={this.state.credentials.username} 
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} 
              placeholder="Username o email"
              onChange={this.onChange}/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Password missing!' }],
          })(
          <Input 
            name="password"
            value={this.state.credentials.password}
            prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} 
            type="password" 
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={this.onChange}/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
              valuePropName: 'checked',
              initialValue: false,
            })(
              <Checkbox>Ricordami</Checkbox>
            )}
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
          Log in
          </Button>
        </FormItem>
        </Form>
    );
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {  
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(sessionActions, dispatch)
  };
}


export default Form.create()(Login);connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

**sessionReducer.js**

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';  
import initialState from './initialState';  

export default function sessionReducer(state = initialState.session, action) {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
      this.context.history.push('/')
      return !!sessionStorage.jwt
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

**sessionActions.js**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';  
import sessionApi from '../api/sessionApi';

export function loginSuccess() {  
  return {type: types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS}
}

export function logInUser(credentials) {  
  return function(dispatch) {
    return sessionApi.login(credentials).then(response => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', response.jwt);
      dispatch(loginSuccess());
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed the problem with the help of @Chaim Friedman but now i got another error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

But i'm using redux-thunk as middleware. Here's login function if it can helps:

**sessionApi.js**

```
import React from 'react'

var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');

class SessionApi {  

  static login(credentials){
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', qs.stringify({auth: credentials}))
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      }),
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing `handleSubmit = (event) => {` as `handleSubmit(event) => {` ?

Comment: In your mapDispatchToProe can you console log what bindActionCreators returns? Find out what you are setting actions to at the point of assignment.

Comment: You are also binding this context twice. Once with the class property assignment and once with the reassign bind in the contructor. Should choose one and be consistent with it.

Comment: I don't now if it's what you said but i think that this is what bindActionCreators returns: `mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_redux__["b" /* bindActionCreators */])(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__actions_sessionActions__, dispatch)
  };
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your trouble is with this line here.

```
export default Form.create()(Login);connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

You are only exporting what `Form.create()` returns, so therefor your component is not actually connected to redux.

To fix this issue you would need to do something like this.

```
export default Form.create(connect(null, matchDispatchToProps)(Login));
```

The exact syntax made be different, it would depend on the usage of `Form.create()`, but this would be the basic idea.

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems to work, but the form isn't rendered. I also got this warning in console: `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: unfortunately I do not know the exact usage of `Form.create()`, but I was just trying to point out that you need to export the combination of both of those higher order components. Sorry I cant be more clear.

Comment: Here's the doc: https://ant.design/components/form/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: I used compose() from https://github.com/acdlite/recompose and i think i've fixed everything, but now i get another error: `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`